# Getting latest from tfs and then building the solution from a batch file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, coded-ui-tests

I have 8 vms, each having the product code. I've created an application using which I can trigger a codedui automation run remotely using mstest. Now the problem is, everytime I have to copy and paste the latest dlls on all the 8 vms to run the recently updated code and the transfering files from local machine to vm takes like eternity to copy over the network.

Is there a way by which I can create a batchfile using which I can download the latest code from the tfs server and then build my codedui test code on each of the VMs?

I know tf get and msbuild can be used for this but I do not know how to use it correctly as getting latest from the server would result in conflicts which needs to be resolved first before building the solution.

Is there a way to replace the entire solution using command line while performing get operation?

Is there a better approach to solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Documentation on the tf.exe GET command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: How many MB/GB are the compiled DLLs?  How many DLLs?  Do all the DLLs change every time or usually only a few? Are all the DLLs the same size or are there a few big ones and the rest small?

Comment: Mainly there's just one dll. But there are xml files also which gets added so getting latest from tfs is a must. If there're major changes then 3-4 dlls get hit.

Comment: Was Mikael's or my answer helpful to you? Did you end up with a solution?

Comment: I haven't tried it out still coz I was a bit away from my laptop. Will let you guys know tomorrow once I try implementing them. Thanks for all the answers. I'll let you know soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use Team Foundation Power Tools ([link to tfpt](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)). It's a very useful little utility =). Specificially, if you want to make sure your workspace is identical to TFS, you could use:

```
tfpt scorch /diff /deletes /recursive /noprompt
```

You probably don't need `/diff` unless you want to check the MD5 diff instead of just the read-only bit (this might also depend on server/local workspaces). The `/recursive` might not do anything in this case as well, because you didn't specify a root folder. That's okay because I think you want to apply this to the entire workspace.

I'm fairly sure you would have to call this from a Visual Studio Dev Prompt. You could add a line to your batch file like:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
```

See this SO post on that: [How to create a Batch File for Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5879076/4183920)

Mikael's post is also a good answer as my answer doesn't help with resolving conflicts. My answer is more along the lines of wiping everything away and restoring it (as needed).

Comment: Just had one question in mind, if i have to just replace those files which have been changed from those in the server version. Can that be done using tfpt?

Comment: I would look at the `tfpt treeclean`, `tfpt scorch` (as mentioned in my answer), and `tfpt uu` Team Foundation Power Tool commands and see which one fits your needs best. My best guess is that `tfpt uu` might be what you're looking for if scorch/treeclean are too heavy-weight.

Comment: Thanks Again for the answer Perry! It really helped!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the entire solution and build from scratch I suggest you just delete the folder and then get it:

```
   rd /s MySolutionFolder
   tf get MySolutionFolder
```

But, this will of course take some time.

Unless you're editing files on the VM, tf get should not trigger any conflicts. If you are editing files, you can use a combination of tf get and tf resolve to deal with those issues. You could use something like this to ignore any conflicts and take the server version.

```
 tf get MySolutionFolder /recursive /noprompt
 tf resolve /auto:taketheirs
```

Comment: OK, great! Would you mind marking it as an answer then?

Comment: I've marked perry's solution as answer since I've used his approach and has worked for me.