# How to open Developer Command Prompt for vs2015?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a .bat file that will open Developer command prompt and there i need to change directory "cd .. " path " " and execute few commands there.

Comment: Have you ever found a satisfactory answer to this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Batch File for Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879076/how-to-create-a-batch-file-for-visual-studio-command-prompt)

Answer (score 2):

Working on this now.

my current .txt file has a hanged extension of (.bat) Which is batch.

Copy & Paste this within your batch file.

```
echo off
title My Test Batch File
:: See the title at the top.
echo Test file executed.
echo I am too lazy to write commands again and again.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>
pause
```

Comment: This will only open the regular command prompt, I'm still trying to get the developer command prompt for VS2015 to open. but it just seems like a normal application, so It should be able to be executed via: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\"

Comment: THanks for the help but i think is opening normal command prompt only :(

Answer (score 2):

The `Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio` is nothing more as the normal cmd with a bat script run at the start.

You can run this script by yourself.

```
call "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on your project name under solution explorer, then locate open command line, select developer command Prompt or use shortcut: shift + Alt + ,