# How to execute process before build multiple projects in a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, project, execute, solution

I'm using VS2010 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.
I want to build multi-project in one solution automatically.

For example : )
Solution `StormSolution` contains 4 projects.

1 : Storm_Module1 (output file extension : dll)

2 : Storm_Module2 (output file extension : dll)

3 : CombineModule12 (output file extension : dat)

4 : ConvertModule2CFGFile (output file extension : cfg)

**Step 1,2** : A result of `Storm_Module1` and `Storm_Module2` are Standard Windows DLL.

**Step 3** : A result of `CombineModule12` is open **Storm_Module1.dll** and **Storm_Module2.dll** to make **"combined.dat"** file, like `cmd.exe /c copy /b storm_module1.dll + storm_module2.dll combined.dat` command.

**Step 3-1** : Then, make **combined.dat** file into **encrypted_combined.dat** file with **encryption_tool**.

**Step 4** : Open "encrypted_combined.dat" file and make it into own specified `cfg` file.

The problem occurs on **Step 4**. I can't build solution storm automatically.
Because I've to make **"combined.dat"** result of `Step3` into **"encrypted_combined.dat"** with **encryption_tool**.

So, if I build Storm solution without any action, `ConvertModule2CFGFile` project can not open latest updated **encrypted_combined.dat**.

How can I execute encryption tool before on **Step4**.

Encryption tool can be executed with parameters.

ex:) `cmd.exe /c "encryption tool.exe -mode_crypt combined.dat -output encrypted_combined.dat`.

Is it impossible to execute process before build project?

Comment: Use def files to create *.lib files for the corresponding *.dll files using lib.exe utility. dll modules need not be kept inside the solution as they are not required during compile time. Keep project linker setting for shared mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can create [Post-Build Events](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.de/2014/02/using-build-events-in-visual-studio-to.html) which can execute a batch file. Use that to combine your two DLLs.

To make your projects build in the correct order, adjust [Build Dependencies and Build Order](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/13/did-you-know-how-to-change-the-build-order-for-your-solution-333/) in your Solution/Projects.

Comment: Thankyou. It works successfully when I typed "Calc.exe" but how can I run my own process? It doesn't work when I typed "D:\Tools\CryptionTool.exe Combined.dll". Error MSB3027 Occured.

Comment: Try using an absolute path to specify your Combined.dll - A portable way would be to use $(SolutionDir) or $(ProjectDir)/bla/Combined.dll

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing a batch file for Visual Studio Command Prompt - it will enable you to build solutions 1 & 2 first, then you can perform any operation on files you like and call your encryption tool easily, and then build the last solution.

This thread should get you started:

[How to create a Batch File for Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879076/how-to-create-a-batch-file-for-visual-studio-command-prompt)